# Optimize Regex to extract content between two tags (or How to select content between two tags with Jsoup selector API?)

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to extract content between two anchor tags from our doc site.

Let's take the [JDK wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) as an example. I want to extract content between "JDK contents" and "Ambiguity between a JDK and an SDK". My current regex is:

```
<span[^>]*\bid\s*=\s*(?:"|')?JDK_contents(?:'|")?[^>]*>([^<]*)</span>(.*?)
(<span[^>]*\bid\s*=\s*(?:"|')?Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK(?:'|")?[^>]*>[^<]*</span>.*)
```

But as this kind of regex would be executed many times, I want to optimize it.

One thing I can consider is the `.*?: </span>(.*?)(<span[^>]...)`
As it will match anything, and cause a lot of backtrack.

btw, I also tried the greedy version: `</span>(.*)(<span[^>]...)`, but it's much slower as the `.*` would match all text, then backtrack till the `Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK` span.

I am using Java. Could anyone help to give some insight?

Comment: Not use if regex is the best solution here. Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Which method(s) do you use with this regexp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive the same with Jsoup's css selector.

**SOLUTION**

```
h2:has(span#JDK_contents) ~ *:not(h2:has(span#Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK) ~ *):not(h2)
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~zba9xj2hAW9_h4x7xWP0a6h0npo)

**DESCRIPTION**

For clarity, let's call `h2Start` an h2 tag having at least one span with id *JDK_contents*. We'll call too `h2End` an h2 tag having at least one span with id *Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK*.

```
h2:has(span#JDK_contents)  /* Select an h2Start */
~ *                        /* Select any node preceded by this h2Start... */
:not(h2:has(span#Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK) ~ *) /* ...but not peceded by an h2End */
:not(h2) /* We remove h2End  */
```

***NOTA:***
In the case of the [JDK wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit), the last line is enough. More rigourously, we would replace it with `:not(h2:has(span#Ambiguity_between_a_JDK_and_an_SDK))`.